# canvas.toDataURL returns blank image

Tags: javascript, canvas, todataurl

I want to draw a table to canvas, then save the canvas as an image. (need to create a pdf)

Funny thing is, the table is displayed on the canvas, but i can't convert it with .toDataURL, it simply returns a blank image.

There is no alert in the console.

```
function getImgDataTable(tableContainer) {
    var tableArea = tableContainer.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].parentNode;
    var doc = tableContainer.ownerDocument;
    var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', tableArea.offsetWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', tableArea.offsetHeight);
    doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
 /* using rasterizeHTML.js */
    rasterizeHTML.drawHTML('<div style="font-size: 20px;">' + $("#data-table-chart-0").html()+ '</div>', canvas);
    var imgDataTable = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(imgDataTable);
    return imgDataTable;
}
```

I am out of ideas, every insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this  http://jsfiddle.net/XtUFt/
html

```
   <div id="c"></div>
<div id="i"></div>
```

js

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.height = canvas.width = 200;
$('#c').append(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//draw a circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(75, 75, 70, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

$('#i').append($('<img/>', { src : dataURL }));
```

Comment: it seems the problem is with the rasterizehtml.js, but i don't seem to understand why. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

It may return blank because you are trying to get the **toDataURL** without waiting for the browser to load the image into the canvas element. So wrap it with **setTimeOut**.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.height = canvas.width = 200;
$('#c').append(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//draw a circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(75, 75, 70, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

setTimeout(function(){
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}, 5000);

$('#i').append($('<img/>', { src : dataURL }));
```